# Jquery form validation real time isn't working on localhost but works on Jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, real-time

This form works perfect on jsfiddle but will not do the same on localhost. I do have the library linked, and have everything just like this:

```
<form  method="post" action="" id="regForm">
    <input type="text" name="user_email">
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#regForm").validate({
            rules: {
                user_email: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But I cannot get the message to appear on the screen on localhost for some reason

http://jsfiddle.net/FbAYz/17/

Comment: What errors, if any, show up in the console? Can you post a more complete example of what you're doing?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" which doesn't make any sense

Comment: Sounds like you did not load the jQuery library, either at all or in the wrong order. It must be loaded **before** the validation script. Hard to say based on what you've shown so far.

Comment: updated libraries on top. i have the libraries then the validation code at the footer of every page

Comment: Please edit your question to show a more complete example of what you're doing. Otherwise, we can only guess. You should also mention what browser(s) you're testing on; IE, for instance, has stricter rules on loading JavaScript locally than every other browser.

Comment: updated. that's my code. im using chrome. the error message is not showing up on localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54374/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-gadgetster).

Answer (score 0):

try this way so that conflicts can be resolved.

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#regForm").validate({
        rules: {
            user_email: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```